# Shared libraries with catkin

Tags: catkin, include, external-libraries, dependencies, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I have a folder called "**lib**" inside my ROS package. The "**lib**" folder has two **.so** libraries (one is named "**librobotsdk.so**") that my package needs (the libraries inside "**lib**" are **not** part of any other ROS package). I am trying to add them to my CMakeList.txt in the next way:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
#link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

But when I do something like this inside my CMakeList.txt:

```
set(EXTRALIB_BIN robotsdk)
```

then I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrobosdk
```

How can I include a library (in this case shared libraries) to my ROS path so tha **cakin_make** can compile it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203315/shared-libraries-with-catkin/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hhmm...it seems that if I do this (without linking directories):

```
set(EXTRALIB_BIN ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/librobosdk.so)
```

and add it to my target libraries list like this:

```
target_link_libraries(executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${EXTRALIB_BIN})
```

then catkin_make does not throw an error any more (program has not been tested yet, just compiled).

Is this the right way to add an external shared library?

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-18**:
Note that catkin is just cmake, and your question should really be "How do I link a shared library without a CMake config file or find script?". What you propose in your answer is one acceptable way (cmake prefers to use absolute paths to libraries).